# Any problems with wrapping Task returning method

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await

Are there any issues that I might encounter by wrapping a method that returns a

```
Task<T> where T : ClassA
```

with a method that returns a

```
Task<T> where T : IClassA
```

In other words wrapping a method that returns a Task of some type with another method that returns a Task of the interface of that type as below:

```
public new Task<ITspIdentity> FindByIdAsync(string id)
{
    return new Task<ITspIdentity>(() => base.FindByIdAsync(id).Result);
}
```

where base.FindByIdAsync(id) would return

```
Task<TspIdentity>.
```

Im having a go at decoupling an ASP.NET MVC applications Presentation tier from a dependency on ASP.Identity by using interfaces.

Comment: Your current implementation is returning a never ending task because you have not started it.

Comment: Blimey - Well that would be at least one problem ;)

Comment: Rather than returning Task<ITSPIdentity> why can't you return Task? That will solve your problem, i suppose

Comment: @Srinivasan__ Op may need result of the task.

Comment: @Srinivasan__ Yes but then I'm just returning a task with result of object which i then need to cast etc. Not too good for testing and general use.

Comment: The problem with this is that you are destroying the async nature of the program by waiting. No need to go async in the first place, then. You get the worst of both worlds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as the calling code doesn't depend on a member that is avaliable only via `ClassA` and not avaliable via `IClassA`, there shouldn't be a problem.

You are creating and returning a `Cold Task` which will run an async method synchronously which is a waste of resources. You can refactor that code and simply do:

```
public new async Task<ITspIdentity> FindByIdAsync(string id)
{
   var tspIdentity = await base.FindByIdAsync(id).ConfigureAwait(false);
   return (ITspIdentity) tspIdentity;
}
```

Comment: No unfortunately I cant do that because Task<ITspIdentity> != Task<TspIdentity>. They are in fact different types.

Comment: Ok now we're talking. tyvm. No Im not concerned about losing access to type due to returning an interface but I was concerned about the the way I went about the conversion. ConfigureAwait = great.